# Mysql memory_global_total is smaller than memory usage in top

Tags: mysql, performance, linux, mysql-5.7, ubuntu

When I try top in my ubuntu the result

```
top - 16:03:09 up 16 days, 21:24,  2 users,  load average: 3.53, 2.72, 3.46
Tasks: 395 total,   1 running, 282 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.0 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.7 id,  1.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16089320 total,   277676 free, 15396176 used,   415468 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 31231996 total, 30194232 free,  1037764 used.   364724 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3529 mysql     20   0 20.627g 0.013t   8084 S 168.2 89.2 533:45.83 mysqld
 5361 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   2.0  0.0   0:01.08 kworker/u32:2
 1234 user      20   0   43052   3280   2324 S   0.7  0.0   2:57.46 top
 5299 user      20   0   43048   3380   2420 R   0.7  0.0   0:14.83 top
 1305 root      20   0 2690104   1992   1256 S   0.3  0.0   2:02.85 snapd
 2355 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.3  0.0
```

but when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM sys.`memory_by_host_by_current_bytes`
```

the result is

```
"total_allocated"
"313.61 MiB"
```

I am using Mysql 5.7.25 running on ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Comment: When a feature is announced as DEPRECATED, that means you can not expect to continue using the feature.  MySQL v5.7.20 included Query Cache notice, per this URL, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html  It is fortunate that your server is still able to survive, most days.

Comment: I know the mysql feature Query Cache is deprecated (in 8.0 and above) but we still do not know what the main cause of the high %MEM